# Accessor ///Comments and T4 templates

Tags: t4

I'm creating accessors for a POCO using T4 templates and when I attempt to generate the accessor comments they don't work when the property is hovered over in VS.

I build the accessors when looping through the columns like so

```
// Accessors
if(i>1){stbAccessors.Append("\t\t");}
if(col.IsForeignKey)
{
    stbAccessors.Append("/// <summary>\r\n\t\t");
    stbAccessors.Append("/// FOREIGN KEY\r\n\t\t");
    stbAccessors.Append("/// <summary>\r\n\t\t");
}
stbAccessors.Append("[DataMember()]\r\n");
stbAccessors.Append("\t\tpublic ").Append(propertyType).Append(" ").Append(col_name).Append("\r\n");
stbAccessors.Append("\t\t{\r\n");
stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\tget { return").Append(" _").Append(col.Name).Append("; }\r\n");
stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\tset\r\n");
stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t{\r\n");
stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t\tif (").Append("_").Append(col.Name).Append(" == value){ return; }\r\n");
stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t\t_").Append(col.Name).Append(" = value;\r\n");
stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t\tChanged = true;\r\n");
stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t}\r\n");
stbAccessors.Append("\t\t}\r\n\r\n");
```

I then generate the accessor code like so.

```
#region " ACCESSORS "

/// <summary>
/// Returns TRUE if data on this object record has changed
/// </summary>
[DataMember()]
public bool Changed { get; set; }

<#=stbAccessors.ToString() #>
#endregion
```

The Changed accessor displays the text "Returns TRUE if data on this object record has changed" properly when hovered over, but any that are marked as "FOREIGN KEY" do not.

Any ideas?
Thanks for any help.

Here is the full code of my DTO generator

```
<#@import namespace="System" #><##>
<#@import namespace="System.IO" #><##>
<#@import namespace="System.Text" #><##>
<#@assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo"#><##>
<#@assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo"#><##>
<#@assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc"#><##>
<#@import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo"#><##>
<#@assembly name="System.Data"#><##>
<#+public void GenerateDTO(Table target_table, string classNamespace, string destinationFolder, string executed_by)
{
    // StringBuilders for Fields, Properties and Parameters.
    StringBuilder stbMembers = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder stbUserSaveEditMembers = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder stbAccessors = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder stbUserSaveEditAccessors = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder stbConstructorParameters = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder stbClassProperties = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder stbUserSaveEditClassProperties = new StringBuilder();

    // Object Name
    string ObjectName = SnakeCaseToCamelCase(target_table.Name);

    // Keep count so we don't whitespace the last property/column
    int columnCount = target_table.Columns.Count;
    int i = 0;
    string col_identity = string.Empty;

    // Iterate all columns
    foreach (Column col in target_table.Columns)
    {
        i++;
        string propertyType = GetNetDataType(col.DataType.Name);

        // If we can't map it, skip it
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyType))
        {
            // Skip
            continue;
        }

        // Make propertytype nullable for nullable columns
        if (col.Nullable && propertyType != "string" && propertyType != "byte[]")
        {
            propertyType += "?";
        }

        // Build Fields & Class Properties
        string col_name = SnakeCaseToCamelCase(col.Name);

        // Capture Identity column name
        if(col.Identity)
        {
            col_identity = col_name;
        }

        // TABLE
        // Members
        stbMembers.Append("private ").Append(propertyType).Append(" _").Append(col.Name).Append(";\r\n\t\t");

        // Accessors
        if(i>1){stbAccessors.Append("\t\t");}
        if(col.IsForeignKey)
        {
            stbAccessors.Append("/// <summary>\r\n\t\t");
            stbAccessors.Append("/// FOREIGN KEY\r\n\t\t");
            stbAccessors.Append("/// <summary>\r\n\t\t");
        }
        stbAccessors.Append("[DataMember()]\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\tpublic ").Append(propertyType).Append(" ").Append(col_name).Append("\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t{\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\tget { return").Append(" _").Append(col.Name).Append("; }\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\tset\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t{\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t\tif (").Append("_").Append(col.Name).Append(" == value){ return; }\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t\t_").Append(col.Name).Append(" = value;\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t\tChanged = true;\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t\t}\r\n");
        stbAccessors.Append("\t\t}\r\n\r\n");

        // Class Properties
        stbClassProperties.Append("_").Append(col.Name).Append(" =").Append(" p").Append(col_name).Append(";");
        if(i < columnCount)
        {
            stbClassProperties.Append("\r\n\t\t\t");
        }

        // Class Parameters
        stbConstructorParameters.Append(propertyType).Append(" p").Append(col_name);
        if(i < columnCount)
        {
            stbConstructorParameters.Append(",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
        }
}#>
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization; 

namespace <#=classNamespace#>
{
    #region " History "

    // <remarks>
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Purpose       : Data Transfer Object for <#=ObjectName #>
    // T4 Template   : DTOGenerator.tt
    // Date Created  : <#=DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy")#>
    // Created By    : <#=executed_by#>
    // Notice        : Copyright © <#=DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy")#> GooeyPC, All rights reserved.
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // History:
    // 
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // </remarks>

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// <#=ObjectName #> Data Transfer Object
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract()]
    public class <#=ObjectName #>DTO
    {
       #region " MEMBERS "

        // TABLE FIELDS 
        <#=stbMembers.ToString() #>
        #endregion

        #region " ACCESSORS "

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns TRUE if data on this object record has changed
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember()]
        public bool Changed { get; set; }

        <#=stbAccessors.ToString() #>
        #endregion

        #region " PROPERTIES - READ ONLY "

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns TRUE if primary key id != 0 (i.e. valid primary key id exists.)
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool RecordExists
        {
            get { return (<#=col_identity #> != 0); }
        }

        #endregion

        #region " CONSTRUCTORS "

        /// <summary>
        /// Description of <#=ObjectName #>
        /// </summary>
        public <#=ObjectName #>DTO()
        {
            // Default constructor is needed
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Description of <#=ObjectName #>
        /// </summary>
        public <#=ObjectName #>DTO(<#=stbConstructorParameters.ToString() #>)
        {            
            // Set Class Properties
            <#=stbClassProperties.ToString() #>
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
<#+
    // Write new class to its own file
    SaveOutput(destinationFolder, ObjectName + "DTO.cs");}
#>
```

This is the code generated for an accessor that is supposed to have the "FOREIGN KEY" comment.

```
/// <summary>
/// FOREIGN KEY
/// <summary>
[DataMember()]
public Int32? YourChildTableNameId
{
    get { return _your_child_table_name_id; }
    set
    {
        if (_your_child_table_name_id == value){ return; }
        _your_child_table_name_id = value;
        Changed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the generated code look like?

Comment: I placed the generated code at the bottom of the OP.

Comment: The XML comment has a syntax error.  The closing tag is missing a forward slash (`</summary>`).

Comment: gah! Thanks! sometimes it's the simplest thing. So embarrassing.